# proof of selection in worst-case linear time

Tags: algorithms, selection-problem

**Introduction to Algorithm,3rd**

**9.3 Selection in worst-case linear time**

I have a question about its proof.

[image]

I have selected that sentence.

[image]

I agree that the number of elements larger than x is

$$ 
    3\times(\lceil\frac{1}{2}\times \lceil\frac{n}{5}\rceil \rceil -2)
$$

but, I think the number of elements less than x is at least
$3\times(\lceil\frac{1}{2}\times \lceil\frac{n}{5}\rceil \rceil)-1$

Am I right? Since the left up side contains $\lceil\frac{1}{2}\times\lceil\frac{n}{5}\rceil\rceil$ groups. Each contribute 3 elements except x itself.

Besides, step5 is

**If i = k, then return x. Otherwise, use SELECT recursively to find the i-th
smallest element on the low side if i < k, or the (i - k)-th smallest element on the high side if i > k.**

How can we get

$$
\frac{7n}{10} + 6
$$
in step 5?

Comment: I know the second problem, that is n-(3n/10-6)

Comment: It's symmetrical, so shouldn't the reasoning be the same for 'number of elements larger than x' and 'number of elements smaller than x'?  Why would you expect to get a different lower bound for those two quantities?  I apologize if I'm missing something.  Oh, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @D.W. Thank you. I count in that figure and find that it's $3\times(\lceil\frac{1}{2}\times \lceil\frac{n}{5}\rceil \rceil)-1$. 
I have a [link, page 26 below](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-6-order-statistics-median/lec6.pdf ) to mit algorithm Fall 2005, it is different from the book.